# How to reduce this to have only one x ...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)=\frac{5}{x+4} $

Reduce the difference quotient in the alternate definition of the derivative below so that you only have one x:
$$\frac{f(x) - f(2)}{x-2}$$

I've gotten down to $\frac{5(10-x)}{x-2}$ . but I can't figure out how to reduce it to one $x$. Am I doing something wrong? I have tried long division, which ended up being incorrect, so I have no idea.

Comment: I suspect you made an error manipulating the fractions. Edit the question to show your steps. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: what do you mean by one $x$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Multiply up and down by $x + 4$
$$\frac{f(x) - f(2)}{x-2}=\frac{5-\frac{5}{6}(x+4)}{(x-2)(x+4)}$$
Multiply up and down by $6$
$$\frac{30-5(x+4)}{6(x-2)(x+4)} = \frac{-5x +10}{6(x-2)(x+4)} = \frac{-5(x-2)}{6(x-2)(x+4)} = -\frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{x+4}$$

Comment: you made an mistake in 2nd equation in last step

Comment: @DeepeshMeena thanks .. edited

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{f(x) - f(2)}{x-2}$$

$$f(2)=\frac{5}{6}$$

$$\frac{\frac{5}{x+4} - \frac{5}{6}}{x-2}$$
$$\frac{30-5x-20}{6(x+4)(x-2)}$$
$$\frac{5(2-x)}{6(x+4)(x-2)}$$

$$\frac{-5}{6(x+4)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$5(10-x)=5(2-x+8)=-5(x-2)+40$$

thus

$$\frac{5(10-x)}{x-2}=-5+\frac{40}{x-2}$$

Comment: I have tried this in the past, and it didn't work.